# Grid display changes on re binding the grid

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a grid on my aspx page.I have set its font property to small..
On page load it is all okay..
but once I perform some action like a delete activity given in the grid itself..and the grid is bound again by recalling the method to bind grid..
the grid seems to be bigger with big fonts.
What could be the trouble?

```
          <asp:GridView ID="grdSMEList" runat="server" Width="100%" BorderWidth="1px" BorderStyle="Solid"
        Font-Size="Small" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderColor="#ffcc00" RowStyle-BorderColor="#ffcc00"
        AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" OnPageIndexChanging="GrdDynamic_PageIndexChanging"
        DataKeyNames="Resource Personnel No" OnRowCommand="GrdDynamic_RowCommand" RowStyle-BorderStyle="Solid"
        RowStyle-BorderWidth="1px" GridLines="Both" Height="104px">
        <PagerSettings NextPageText="&amp;gt;&amp;gt" PageButtonCount="5" PreviousPageText="&amp;lt;&amp;lt"
            FirstPageText="" LastPageText="" Mode="Numeric" />
        <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Font-Size="Medium" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Resource Personnel No" HeaderText="Resource Personnel No" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RES Name" HeaderText="ResourceName" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Deactivate" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div style="text-align:center;">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="linkDeactivate" CommandName="cmdDeactivate" OnRowCommand="GrdDynamic_RowCommand"
                            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Resource Personnel No") %>' OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Deactivate?');"
                            runat="server">Deactivate</asp:LinkButton>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="2%" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try specifying the font color in ItemTemplate ? Its worth a try.